# Using form validator ZOD's discriminatedUnion() function to distinguish between 3 forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, zod

```
ValidationSchema = z.object({
AuthenticationBlock: z.object({
  ChoiceOfForm: z.enum()
  DataBlock: z.discriminatedUnion(ChoiceOfForm, [
     z.object({ ChoiceOfForm = 1, empty fields}) //corresponds to the basic form
     z.object({ ChoiceOfForm = 2, just username/pw fields) //corresponds to less basic form
     z.object({ ChoiceOfForm = 3, user/pw + many fields}) //corresponds to advanced form
    ])
  })
})
```

Example of an object:

```
export type AuthenticationFormValues = {
    AuthenticationBlock?: {
        choice?: AuthenticationFormChoice | undefined;
        data: {
            password?: string;
            username?: string;
            formAuthenticationConfig?: {
                formUrl?: string;
                javaScriptLoadingDelayInMilliseconds?: number;
                forceLogin?: boolean;
                customLoginSequence?: string;
                authenticationFailed?: FormAuthenticationFailedConfiguration;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

**choiceOfForm** is an ENUM corresponding to 3 radio buttons that collapse different forms (1, 2 or 3). I would like to use ZOD's discriminatedUnion() function to enable the correct form validation block depending on which choiceOfForm is selected (1,2 or 3). Is there a way to pass the choiceOfForm variable to the discriminatedUnion(choiceOfForm, ...) to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Please show your example object

Comment: @KonradLinkowski   export type AuthenticationFormValues = {
    AuthenticationBlock?: {
        choice?: AuthenticationFormChoice | undefined;
        data: {
            password?: string;
            username?: string;
            formAuthenticationConfig?: {
                formUrl?: string;
                javaScriptLoadingDelayInMilliseconds?: number;
                forceLogin?: boolean;
                customLoginSequence?: string;
                authenticationFailed?: FormAuthenticationFailedConfiguration;
            };
        };
    };
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you're looking for with something like:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

enum ChoiceOfForm {
  Option1 = 1,
  Option2 = 2,
  Option3 = 3
}

// Defining this once since it's shared between two of the arms.
const PasswordFields = z.object({
  password: z.string(),
  email: z.string().email()
});

const schema = z.discriminatedUnion("choice", [
  z.object({
    choice: z.literal(undefined),
  }),
  z.object({
    choice: z.literal(ChoiceOfForm.Option1)
  }),
  z.object({
    choice: z.literal(ChoiceOfForm.Option2)
  }).merge(PasswordFields),
  z.object({
    choice: z.literal(ChoiceOfForm.Option3),
    extraOption: z.number()
  }).merge(PasswordFields)
]);
```

Zod's [`discriminatedUnion`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#discriminated-unions) function takes the key you are going to discriminate on as the first argument and a list of schemas for each "branch" of the union. Note that virtually any object will be parsed successfully with this schema because of the `z.literal(undefined)` option. You may want to omit that as a possibility, but I'm not certain of your business requirements.

If you successfully parse something with this schema, you can check the value of `choice` with a `switch` or `if` statement and narrow the types as you would with a regular discriminated union.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing, thanks for the write-up!